# In Rational Team Concert v5.0.2 how to get members list in workitem dropdown attribute?

Tags: rtc, rational-team-concert

I want to add a attribute "Person Responsible:" and it should provide me a list of all members/users added within the project area, to allow me select a user. Just as what we have for "Owned by:".
How to get implement this.
I have RTCv5.0.2.

Comment: Hi, I know how to create the enumerations but then it will not give autopopulated list of project members in the dropdown as it does in the "Owned by:" or "Created by:" field. I also tried to immitate the "owned by:" field, for that I created a custom attirubute and added the kind=contributor, then added it to editor presentation. The label showed up in web but the dropdown didnt come up.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom attribute of type contributor (or contributor list).